# Laravel 8 Yajra DataTable refresh on the same page

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

How can I refresh a DataTable in the current page number without going back to the first page?
This code refresh the table but keeps going to the first page or the first link of the pagination.

```
$('#table_users').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

This is how the table is initialized.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // init datatable.
            var dataTable = $('#table_users').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                pageLength: 10,
                // scrollX: true,
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ route('get_users') }}'
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                    {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                    {data: 'sex', name: 'sex'},
                    {data: 'bday', name: 'bday'},
                    {data: 'contact', name: 'contact'},
                    {data: 'scope', name: 'scope'},
                    {data: 'roles', name: 'roles'},
                    {data: 'permissions', name: 'permissions'},
                ]
            });
        });
```

The controller.

```
    $user = User::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'sex', 'bday', 'contact', 'scope', 'scope_id')->get();
    return \DataTables::of($user)->make()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace datatable reload with this,

```
dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false)
```

Where the `dataTable` is an **instance of created datatable** and set first param as null which is **callback** and second param is for **reset paging** so set it as **false**.

Let me know its solve your issue or not.

[Reference](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Comment: Worked perfectly, `$('#table_users').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);`

Comment: additional you can see here also about Q&A related to Datatable :- https://www.py4u.net/discuss/913396